# programmatic control of PDFCreator

Tags: c#, pdf, outlook, msg

I want to print `Outlook .msg` files to PDF programatically. Since I cannot set `ActivePrinter` using `C# AddIn` in Outlook, I am searching if there is any way to use `PDFCreator`.

I found, that you can call `PDFCreator` with `/PF<filename`> option, and it will print specified file to PDF using its default launcher. So I tried this on `.msg` file, it prints them perfectly, but user must interact with `PDFCreator` GUI to choose save location and some other stuff...

So, is there any way, command or script I can use to convert `.msg` file to PDF using `PDFCreator` programatically, `without user input at all`?

Comment: `B.GenJackONeil` are you wanting to safe to a static location for all users who use the GUI..? if so just Save it to a specific location on their machine and if necessary, prompt a MsgDialog to alert the end user as to where the file is being saved.

Comment: John: Sorry, I thought it compiles "the they are organic to the conversational tone of the title" exception.

DJ KRAZE: No, I want to programatically specify location each time I want to convert new msg, and it must all run on background, without requiring user actions.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

PDFCreator implements COM object, which you can use. And it (pdfcreator) ships with examples of usage, including VB and C# examples.